# how to delete flask session after closing browser tab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, session, flask-session

how do I delete all `flask-session` data as soon as the `browser-tab` is closed.

I know that session data gets deleted automatically after `browser-window` is closed but is there any way to delete session data after closing the tab.

Comment: That's unreliable. The user could have more than one tab open. What you can do is change the timeout default value.

Comment: I have kept timeout value at 30 mins